# Explayar select con datos de BD

Tags: php, html, input

llevo programando varios días, y ahora me encuentro abrumado, necesito ayuda

El contexto es el siguiente:

Tengo un form #1 donde el usuario selecciona el horario de atención de su negocio, pero solo ingresando la hora de inicio y salida AM y PM

Entonces la Base de datos lo único que estoy registrando es:

- Hora de Inicio AM: ej: 8:00
- Hora de Salida AM ej: 12:00
- Hora de Inicio PM ej: 16:00
- Hora de Salida PM ej: 20:00

Obteniendo estos 4 datos, necesito mostrarlos en un select para un form #2, que se explaye del siguiente modo:

Utilizaría un "select" en vez de un input "time", ya que necesito mostrar en especifico cada media hora, por ejemplo:

```
    <optgroup label="Mañana">
      <option value="8:00">8:00</option>
      <option value="8:30">8:30</option>
      <option value="9:00">9:00</option>
      <option value="9:30">9:30</option>
      <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
      <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
      <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
      <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
      <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Tarde">
      <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
      <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
      <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
      <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
      <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
      <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
      <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
      <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
      <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
```

*Este select es parte de otro formulario que no viene al caso*

¿Como puedo mostrar esta información solo teniendo esos 4 datos?, pense en utilizar "for" pero estoy en un verengenal.

Espero haber sido claro. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar `strtotime()` para convertir tu hora inicial y hora final y luego hacer un `for` que te cree todos los elementos desde inicial hasta final con el incremento en tiempo que desees

Como no sé bien lo que deseas hacer (Tal vez directamente crear los `<option>` para los select o solo crear strings para usarlos de alguna forma) te dejo un ejemplo que solo hace `echo` desde `$horaInicio` a `$horaFinal` con incremento de 30 minutos

Si no deseas incluir los segundos puedes quitarle la `s` a la línea `echo date("H:i:s", $i) . "\n";`

```
<?php
$horaInicio = "08:00";
$horaFinal = "16:00";

for ($i = strtotime($horaInicio); $i <= strtotime($horaFinal); $i = strtotime("+30 minute", $i)) {
    echo date("H:i:s", $i) . "\n";
}
?>
```

Para más información sobre el formato de fecha y hora puedes visitar [este sitio](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_create_from_format.asp)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, lo adapte para que mostrara los <option> y funciono de maravilla.